# Авторизация для вебсокета через laravel passport

Tags: laravel, websocket, passport

У меня есть приватный канал что бы к нему подключится нужно быть авторизованным на сайте.
Но мне нужно авторизовываться посредством personal access token. Как это реализовать?

сейчас есть вот такой код.

```
Broadcast::routes();
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

В поисках я натыкался на вот такой кусок кода `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api']]);`, но прописав только это ничего ровным счетом не изменилось.

Comment: [Вот тут расписал как реализовано у меня](https://toster.ru/q/548355)